# Ubuntu won't let me log in?

Tags: 14.04

I turned on my computer and typed in my password. I'm 100% sure it was correct, but my computer said it was incorrect. I tried about 15 times and still got the same answer. I havn't changed my password since I set it. What's going on?

Comment: Maybe you misspelled your password while setting it up first time. Try to variate with shift (caps lock) and num lock options... Num lock is never on on log-in screen by default.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot into Ubuntu using the "live" CD.
2. Mount your HDD, usually under /media. (Use Disks for mounting)
3. Enter terminal mode (as a superuser).
4. [chroot](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-chroot-command-examples-usage-syntax/) to the HDD installation mount point.
5. Change the user password with the [passwd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/passwd.1.html) command.
6. Reboot without the "live" CD.

Thanks to the [RockDoctor](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/unable-to-get-past-login-screen-passwords-not-recognized-4175440904/#post4846934) as the source of the above solution.